# Is this the correct way to derive the generating series?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

This is from my textbook, which has no solutions for any of the problems (bad).

> Determine the generating series for the number of 5-combinations where M, A, T, H in which M and A can appear any number of times but T and H  can appear at most once.

Can I just treat this as a Cartesian product of quantities of M, A, T, and H respectively and give a generating function with respect to sum as

$$\Phi_S(x)=(1+x+x^ 2+\cdots)^2(1+x)^ 2$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks right to me.  The number of 5-combinations is the coefficient of x^5, but I suppose you know that already.  I'm assuming the order of the letters is irrelevant.